# classic asp files include files

Tags: scripting, asp-classic, vbscript, include, server-side-includes

I have a classic asp application that uses an include file. The include file is a footer at the end of the page and works fine until the page is large and then the include file stop displaying.

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Do a search for `response.end` and see if any of the code is forcing it to stop displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you end the response prior to the include directive, then the included file will not be displayed.

This could be caused by either (a) a `Response.End` or (b) an exception.  Sometimes the exception won't be visible because it is within a non-visible element.  View the page source to look for these and scroll to the end.

Check the 'long file' and see if either of these occurs.

Another possibility with very large files is that the file hasn't finished rendering the page.  Make sure that the whole page has rendered.